# How to Give Default Value to TextField , NumberFormat Exception in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to give a default value to a TextField , I have two TextFields ( it has two controller which is _HeightInFeetController and _HeightInInchesController ) , and two double variables which is (HeightInFeet , HeightInInches  ) ,  when I don't want to give value or to input (leave is empty not even input zero) in one of the textfields and I press the button it throws NumberFormatException (Invalid Double) , Help me ,in initstate method I gave 0.0 to both double values though ,  I appreciate your answer ❤.

```
  HeightInFeet = double.parse(_HeightInFeetController.text);
   HeightInInches = double.parse(_HeightInInchesController.text);
   RaisedButton.icon(onPressed: () {
   print("$HeightInFeet");
   print("$HeightInInches");
   } )
```

Comment: You're trying to parse on a null or say empty value. That's the reason. Add a condition to check if the value is not null and empty before parsing the input to double

Comment: Thank you so much brother , this really helped me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try tryParse()

`HeightInInches = double.tryParse(_HeightInInchesController.text);`

this syntax return null if `_HeightInInchesController.text` is not applicable to convert in double.

Comment: Thank you bro , but I said if it is empty , so this is the solution that someone gave me the idea .

Comment: if(_HeightInInchesController.text.isEmpty || _HeightInInchesController.text == null){
                    _HeightInInchesController.text = "0.0";
                  }                                                             
                  if(_HeightInFeetController.text.isEmpty || _HeightInFeetController.text == null){
                    _HeightInFeetController.text = "0.0";
                  }

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/double/tryParse.html please refer this

Comment: controller.text is never null. it is by default empty string as far as I know